# Script only runs in some browsers when head tags are removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, tumblr

I'm using a tumblr theme which is structured like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <style>
        </style>
        <body>
        </body>
    </html>
```

There are no head tags which I thought was strange but it works fine; because when you run the site it places head tags automatically. However, since I'm using plugins I added the head tags myself to give me better control as some required me to place it in `<head>`. This worked fine in chrome and safari but it disabled one of my scripts in firefox and IE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var speed = 25,
        timer;
    $("#hoverscroll").hover(function () {
        $(this).css({cursor: 'none'});
        $(this).css({opacity: '0'});
        var div = $('body');
        (function startscrolling(){
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                var pos = div.scrollTop();
                div.scrollTop(pos + 1);
                startscrolling();
            }, speed);
        })();
    },

    function () {
        $("#hoverscroll").css({opacity: '1'});
        clearTimeout(timer);
        speed = 25;
    })
    .click(function(){
         speed = 1;
    });

});
```

It's a simple script where it scrolls the page when an element is hovered.

I reproduced the problem in these 2 demo-sites:

http://testmycode.tumblr.com/ This site has head tag, scrolls in chrome, does not scroll in Firefox.

http://testmycode2.tumblr.com/ This site has **no** head tag, works perfectly and scrolls in **all** browsers.

Comment: You could add your script tag just after the opening body tag and see how it works.

Comment: It's *highly* unlikely that the presence or absence of `<head>` is causing your problem. You should check the IE developer tools console for errors.

Comment: I just added 2 demo sites. One with head tags and one without. As you can see the head tags is determining whether the script works or not. Could it be because I'm using 'body' as a selector?

Comment: tumblr not opening here, check and compare the head tags with and without your own head tag to see if they match using console!

Answer (score 0):

you can add code to your head tag using JQuery like below

```
$("head").append("<script src=\"mypluginscript.js\"></script>");
```

this will let you add any new code to it without having to write the head tag

[an example!](http://jsfiddle.net/vL2Dc/1/)

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: @Pointy the OP is adding head tags when it is already being added, if anything new need to be added to that head tag(like OP wants), why not add it.

Comment: @T_01 why T_01?... why?... o.O?

Comment: That might work.. it's more of a workaround though. I'll try it if there's no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

> 'However, since I'm using plugins I added the head tags myself to give
>   me better control'

**What you mean by that?**

Most of the times there is an alternative solution.

---

A proper html needs a html tag a head tag and a body tag

inside the head tag you put meta,script and style tags

minimal structure is

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Else it's not a html file.

Almost TEN years html5 was launched....

and as it is similar to the basic structure it works on all browsers.

```
<!doctype html> // html5
<html lang="en"> // language set to english
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> // can decode almost al charachters éçàò..
<style></style>
<script></script>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

now reguarding your code.

```
<script>
```

goes inside head (or at the end of the body [or just after each element])

if you put the code in the head..

to handle elements inside the body

you need to add a window.onload // DOMContentLoaded

else you have no access to the dom elements.

---

Now looking at your code from Chrome the errors starts on the html tag..

Why the html has a webkit animation?

Then your talking about the doctype tag and not the head tag.
So if you tell us why you need that we can probably find a solution.

Comment: Google analytics, ad codes usually goes in the Head section. Since there were no initial head tags in the theme, I added those myself. I'm not sure what you are trying to prove by the rest of your post but it has nothing to do with my question.. The webkit animation belongs to another theme, which I used for the demo site and has once again nothing to do with the problem. I'm sorry if this sounds rude but I don't understand what you are trying to prove.

Comment: webkit animation should be inside the body...as  you can't animate the head and if it works it's wrong.anddon't you mean the doctype tag?